# java no main classes found error when the program said build successful

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi I'm currently doing this program for my assignment to create like a virtual shop. Currently I'm using NetBean IDE 8.1 and got an error when I tried to test the program. It's said , even though the program said build successful when I tried to build the program.

I did tried to follow the instruction in this  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vTbonqij_Q) but came out empty [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL5H3.png)

Here is my main program ( I haven't complete the program yet but this error keeps blocking me for testing it)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Zarashop {
 int choice;
 public static void main(String[] args, int clothA){
    Scanner absorb = new Scanner(System.in);

    // phase 1 login
    cloth cl = new cloth(); // declaring objects
    payment pay = new payment();
    personalinfo pi = new personalinfo();
    shipping ship = new shipping();
    receipt re = new receipt();
    System.out.println("Welcome to Zara's cloth Shopping Center");
    System.out.println("\nThis an online Shopping application will help you to buy "+ "a new cloth");
    System.out.println("Please enter your detail");
     System.out.println("\nPlease enter your name");
     String Name = absorb.nextLine(); // user input name
     System.out.println("\nAre you a student? (yes) or (no)");
     String personalchoice = absorb.nextLine(); // user input status


     //phase 2
     System.out.println("please choose your cloth" );
     System.out.println("cloth A detail : size: 170cm and red color  ");
     int cloathA = absorb.nextInt(); 
     System.out.println("enter quantity  ");
     int quantity = absorb.nextInt(); 

     pay.setclothA(clothA); // store value
     pay.setquantity(quantity); 

     // phase 3 payment
     System.out.println("please press 1 to calculate your payment");
     int choice = absorb.nextInt();
     if(choice == 1){
         pay.total();    
     }
     else {
    System.err.println("error!");
  } 
   }





    }
```

Here is my main class for cloth ( misspelled was intended)

```
   public class cloth {

  // superclass
   private int quantity; //  
 private int  clothA=200;
 //void
 void setclothA(int ca){
     clothA = ca;
 }
void setquantity(int q){
    quantity=q;
}

//get

int getclothA(){
    return clothA;
}
int getquantity(){
    return quantity;
    }

  }
```

my main class for personalInfo

```
 public class personalinfo {

// superclass
public String Name; 
private int Password; 
private String TypeCard; 
private int CardNo;   
private String Address; 
private int TeleNo;   

//void


void setName(String n){
    Name = n;
}
void setPassword(int p){
    Password = p;
}
void setTypeCard(String tp){
    TypeCard = tp;
}
void setCardNo ( int cn){
    CardNo=cn;
}
void setAddress ( int a){
    CardNo=a;
}
void setTeleNo ( int tl){
    TeleNo=tl;
}
   //get

String getName(){
    return Name;

}
String getAddress(){
    return Address;
  }
     int getPassword(){
         return Password;
     }
     String getTypeCard(){
         return TypeCard;
     }
     int getCardNo(){
         return CardNo;
     }
     int getTeleNo (){
         return TeleNo;
     }
  }
```

my sub class for payment
         package zarashop;

```
  //subclass
  public class payment extends cloth {
 String Status = "Initial";
public void total(){

int ca = super.getclothA(); //fetching values
int q = super. getquantity();
int total= q*ca;

  }
 }



    public class receipt extends shipping{



}
```

my sub for shipping

```
public class shipping extends payment  {
public int typeofshipping; 
//void 
void settypeofshipping(String ts){
    String typeofshipping = ts;
   }
  int gettypeofshipping(){
        return typeofshipping;
  } 
   }
```

subclass for receipt (i'm reserving this for the program to display all the necessary user input)

```
 public class receipt extends shipping{



 }
```

thank you everyone and sorry for my bad program and my English.

Comment: The main method is supposed to be `public static void main(String[])`, not `public static void main(String[], int)`.

Comment: if you got answered your question you should accept it, marking the best answer for you with a check.

Answer (score 4):

A Java application can accept any number of arguments from the command line, and all of those are interpreted as `String`, that's why main only takes an array of String as parameter.

Change you code to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and you'll be able to launch your application.

If you need to support a numeric command-line argument, you must convert a String argument that represents a number to an int:

```
int firstArg;
if (args.length > 0) {
    try {
        firstArg = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Argument" + args[0] + " must be an integer.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

parseInt throws a NumberFormatException if the format of args[0] isn't valid.

The example comes from [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake: `public static void main(String[] args**, int clothA**)`

Change it to **`public static void main(String[] args)`**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your main method to `public static void main(String[] args)`. By adding int clothA as a second argument, you are chaging the signature, and then it becomes an invalid main method to launch your application from.

If you want to retrieve something from console, you will find your argument inside args.

You can then retrieve clothA as follows:

```
int clothA;
if (args.length > 0) {
    try {
        clothA = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Argument" + args[0] + " must be an integer.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone!